# IE (at least 11) and Edge not recognizing a .length property in d3.js

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, d3.js

I'm building a set of "dials" and menus for a web page mainly using d3.js. Everything draws as supposed in Chrome and Firefox, but IE11 and Edge seem to have a problem mainly figuring out the following **d.name.length** property:

```
function drawChart2(data2) {

var arc2 = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius(chartHeight/1.4)
    .innerRadius(chartHeight/1.25)
    .padAngle(0.01);

var halfPie = d3.pie()
    .value(function(d) { return d.name.length; })
    .startAngle(90 * (Math.PI/180))
    .endAngle(Math.PI);

var rimG = rimChart.selectAll('g')
    .remove()
    .exit()
    .data([data2])
    .enter()
    .append('g');

var block2 = rimG.selectAll('.rim')
    .data(halfPie)
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .classed('rim', true);
```

This is part of a process of creating a "menu" on-the-fly where the slot sizes/widths are based on the underlying menu (data) item / text length, creating something along these lines:

[Arched dial menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUsX7.png)

However, I get the following error message e.g. under IE11:

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'length': object is null or undefined

If I hardcode a length value instead of using d.name.length, the same error remains, but now seemingly in d3.js itself: File: d3.v4.min.js, row: 5, column: 5647, in the following code:

```
var a,c,s,f,l,h=t.length
```

Now I've read about problems in MS browsers with length properties, but cannot really pinpoint the problem here. Is this an issue in my code here or a general d3.js vs. IE compatibility thing, and is there a reasonable IE workaround for getting the length property of d.name?

Comment: Could you set up a [mcve], i.e. an executable demo as a Stack Snippet, JSFiddle, Codepen or the like?

Comment: What is the type of d.name here? Is it an SVGLengthList?